# Creating a Powershell menu from from config file

Tags: arrays, powershell, menu, config

I have been trying to build a menu from a config file in Powershell.  The purpose of the menu is to call other scripts and executables and to make maintenance easier so I can easily update the config whenever I need to add menu items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I strongly recommend you to use config files in XML format. Its REALLY much useful. I have came up with solution like this:

```
#Assuming this is content of your XML config file. You could easily add new Ids to insert new actions.
[xml]$Config=@"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Menu>
    <Actions>
        <Id>
            <Choice>1</Choice>
            <Script>C:\DoThis.ps1</Script>
            <Description>Will do this</Description>
        </Id>
        <Id>
            <Choice>2</Choice>
            <Script>C:\DoThat.ps1</Script>
            <Description>Will do that</Description>
        </Id>
    </Actions>
</Menu>
"@

#Here's the actual menu. You could add extra formating if you like.

$Message = ''
$Continue = $true    

DO 
{
    cls
    Write-Host 'Welcome to the menu!'
    Write-Host ''

    if ($Message -ne '')
    {
        Write-Host ''
    }

    foreach ($Item in @($Config.Menu.Actions.Id))
    {
        Write-Host ("{0}.`t{1}." -f $Item.Choice,$Item.Description)
    }
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host "Q.`tQuit menu."
    Write-Host ''

    $Message = ''
    $Choice = Read-Host 'Select option'
    if ($Choice -eq 'Q'){$Continue = $false} #this will release script from DO/WHILE loop.

    $Selection = $Config.Menu.Actions.Id | ? {$_.Choice -eq $Choice}
    if ($Selection)
    {
        cls
        Write-Host ("Starting {0}" -f $Selection.Description)
        & $Selection.Script
        Write-Host ''
    }
    else
    {
        $Message = 'Unknown choice, try again'

    }
    if ($Continue)
    {
        if ($Message -ne '')
        {
            Write-Host $Message -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        Read-Host 'Hit any key to continue'
    }
    cls
}
WHILE ($Continue)
Write-Host 'Exited menu. Have a nice day.'
Write-Host ''
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the menu!

1.  Will do this.
2.  Will do that.

Q.  Quit menu.

Select option:
```

Comment: Hi this is going to work great, seems so much cleaner and easier with XML.
Just updated the script so it reads in my XML file so that can be updated separately.
Thanks.